# scatter plot in r with huge unique observation

Tags: r, plot, distribution, scatter-plot, outliers

Currently, plot is not useful. How would I plot this distribution, since the range is too high?

I have data of 50 year and have to see which activity is most harmful.

The data contain about 1000 unique activity say `column1`.
I am using `groupby(column1)` and `summarise(total  = sum(column2,column3))`
but problem is there few total value in 6 to 7 digit 
because of these two fact my plot x look bad and due few  high value y most value are near x axis.

[image: SS of plot]

I believe the problem is at x axis since so many names are clustered together due to less space.

Comment: I am unsure, but this might be more relevant to the stats.stackexchange.com forum, however just looking at the plot, I guess you could either get rid of the outliers by filtering out points with a value greater than the one you want. Or you could change the plotting setting so that your Y-axis is defined by you instead of the standard scale which will encompass all the points. I am sure that both of these methods have been discussed and described in this forum and in the R documentation.

Comment: Use of log scale?

Answer (score 2):

I think a log transformation might help you gain some better insight out of your data:

### Set up some fake data that resembles your situation:

```
set.seed(1776)        # reproducible random numbers
num_obs <- 10000      # set number of observations
options(scipen = 999) # don't use scientific notation

# don't worry about this code, just creating a reproducible example
y <- abs(rnorm(num_obs) + 2) * abs(rnorm(num_obs) * 50)
make_these_outliers <- runif(num_obs, min=0, max=1) > 0.99
y[make_these_outliers] <- abs(rnorm(sum(make_these_outliers), + 2) * 
abs(rnorm(sum(make_these_outliers)) * 50000))
```

### Recreate the plot you have now to show the issue you're facing:

```
# recreating your current situation
plot(y, main='Ugly Plot')
```

[image: ugly plot]

### Log10 transformation

Now we'll use the log10 transformation on your data an visualize the result. So a value of "10" is now "1", value of "100" is now "2", value of "1000" is now "3", etc.

```
# log10
plot(log10(y), col= rgb(0, 0, 0, alpha=0.3), pch=16, main='Log Scale and Transparency - Slightly Better')
```

[image: log10_base_R]

The `pch = 16` argument fills in the points and the `alpha = 0.4` sets the opacity of each point. An alpha of 0.4 means an opacity of 40% (can also think of this as 60% transparent).

### ggplot2

I'll also show this in ggplot2, because using the scale transformations, ggplot2 is smart enough to put the true value on the y-axis to prevent you from having to do the mental gymnastics of log10 transforms in your head.

```
# now with ggplot2 
# install.packages("ggplot2")    # <-- run this if you haven't installed ggplot2 yet
library(ggplot2)

# ggplot2 prefers your data to be in a data.frame (makes it easier to work with)
data_df <- data.frame(
    index = 1:num_obs,
    y = y)


ggplot(data = data_df, aes(x = index, y = y)) +
    geom_point(alpha=0.2) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans="log10") +
    ggtitle("Y-axis reflects values of the datapoints", "even better?") +
    theme_bw(base_size = 12)
```

[image]

At this point, you can start to tell how I've constructed the fake data, which is why there is such a high concentration of points in the 10-1000 range.

Hopefully this helps! I definitely recommend taking PauloH's advice and asking around on stats.stackexchange.com as well to make sure you aren't misrepresenting your data.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ggplot2` instead and setting alpha may solve your problem but if that is not enough you may want tag along `zoom_facet()` from the `ggforce` package.

```
set.seed(1776)      
num_obs <- 10000     
options(scipen = 999) 

y <- abs(rnorm(num_obs) + 2) * abs(rnorm(num_obs) * 50)
make_these_outliers <- runif(num_obs, min=0, max=1) > 0.99
y[make_these_outliers] <- abs(rnorm(sum(make_these_outliers), + 2) * 
                                abs(rnorm(sum(make_these_outliers)) * 50000))

# install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)
# install.packages('ggforce')
library(ggforce)

data_df <- data.frame(
  index = 1:num_obs,
  y = y)


ggplot(data = data_df, aes(x = index, y = y)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.05) +
  facet_zoom(y = (y <= 500), zoom.size = .8) +
  theme_bw()
```

The result would look more or less like the following:
[image]

Hope it helps. Check the `ggforce`'s GitHub:

https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce